# Finding and replacing text in c#

Tags: c#, regex, import, find

I need to add functionality in my program so that any file imported it will find the text within the "" of the addTestingPageContentText method as seen below. The two values on each line will then be added to a datagridview which has 2 columns so first text in first column then second in the 2nd column. How would i go about Finding the "sometext" ?

```
    addTestingPageContentText("Sometext", "Sometext");
    addTestingPageContentText("Sometext2", "Sometext2");
... continues n number of times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither fast nor efficient, but it's easier to understand for those new to regular expressions:

```
while (!endOfFile)
{
    //get the next line of the file
    string line = file.readLine();

    EDIT: //Trim WhiteSpaces at start
    line = line.Trim();
    //check for your string
    if (line.StartsWith("addTestingPageContentText"))
    {
        int start1;
        int start2;
        //get the first something by finding a "
        for (start1 = 0; start1 < line.Length; start1++)
        {
            if (line.Substring(start1, 1) == '"'.ToString())
            {
                start1++;
                break;
            }
        }
        //get the end of the first something
        for (start2 = start1; start2 < line.Length; start2++)
        {
            if (line.Substring(start2, 1) == '"'.ToString())
            {
              start2--;
              break;
            }
        }
        string sometext1 = line.Substring(start1, start2 - start1);
        //get the second something by finding a "
        for (start1 = start2 + 2; start1 < line.Length; start1++)
        {
            if (line.Substring(start1, 1) == '"'.ToString())
            {
                start1++;
                break;
            }
        }
        //get the end of the second something
        for (start2 = start1; start2 < line.Length; start2++)
        {
            if (line.Substring(start2, 1) == '"'.ToString())
            {
                start2--;
                break;
            }
        }
        string sometext2 = line.Substring(start1, start2 - start1);
    }
}
```

However I would seriously recommend going through some of the great tutorials out there on the internet. [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is quite a good one

Comment: Watch out for whitespace at the beginning of the line. That will throw off your `line.StartsWith("addTestingPageContentText")` condition.

Comment: You can also replace those `for` loops with `string.IndexOf`.

Comment: Good call, I assumed the whitespace there was an error from the conversion to code in the post, not in the data. In that case, trimming whitespace with string.Trim() would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `"\"[^"]*\""` would find each...